# Characterization of non-Zeno functions $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \{0,1\}$

Tags: set-theory, recreational-mathematics, definitions, automata-theory

*[**Edit:** I tried to integrate Nate's comments (see below).]*

---

In the context of [automata over continuous time](https://ac.els-cdn.com/S0304397502003316/1-s2.0-S0304397502003316-main.pdf?_tid=45f884ee-f452-11e7-99c1-00000aab0f6c&acdnat=1515402166_90aa16d8fcd577c43899cacb080874e2), consider Boolean-valued functions $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \{0,1\}$. There are uncountably many – exactly $2^\mathbb{R}$ – of them.

I'm trying to figure out how those

> ***functions with finitely many switches between $0$ and $1$ and compact support***

might be described in a general and compact way.

First I tried to imagine how such a function may switch its values:

- (**1**) [image]
- (**2**) [image]
- (**3**) [image]
- (**4**) [image]
- (**5**) [image]
- (**6**) [image]

Assuming that these are all the ways there are, each function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \{0,1\}$ with compact support and finitely many switches $\sigma_i$, $i = 0,\dots n$ occuring at times $t_i \in \mathbb{R}$ should be uniquely definable by a sequence

> $$\sigma_i = \langle \tau_i, \lambda_i\rangle$$

with

1. $\lambda_{i} \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$, $\lambda_{i} = t_{i+1} - t_i$ for $i < n$
2. $\tau_i \in \{(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6)\}$,
3. $\tau_0$ must be (1),(3), or (4),
4. $\tau_n$ must be (1),(5), or (6),
5. $\tau_{i}$ must obey

[image]

(And vice versa: Each such sequence defines such a function.)

> **Is this correct?**

Obviously, there are still uncountably many functions of this kind, as there are uncoutably many parameters $\lambda_i$. Setting all these to $1$ the question arises:

> **How many sequences $\{\tau_i\}_{i=0,\dots,n}$ obeying 2.-5. (see above) are
>   there (depending on $n$).**

---

Comment: Sounds like perhaps you are looking for [step functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Step_function), with the added restriction that only 0 and 1 values are allowed?  The requirement to "start and end at 0" can be added by saying "compactly supported".

Comment: Note that there are a couple different versions of 3,4, depending on the value taken at the jump point.  Consider $1_{(0,1]}$ versus $1_{[0,1]}$.

Comment: Are (1) and (2) allowed in "classic" step functions?

Comment: Concerning your second comment: What difference would it make? How would one want to reflect it?

Comment: It depends on whether you consider a point to be an interval.  It's not much of a stretch to think of $\{x\} = [x,x]$ as an interval.  The term "step function" doesn't really have a single universal definition; it's loose enough to use for anything that's in the same spirit.  I would write something like "$f = \sum_{k=1}^n 1_{I_k}$ where the $I_k
$ are pairwise disjoint closed/open/half-open intervals or singletons".

Comment: I mean, $1_{(0,1]}$ and $1_{[0,1]}$ are certainly different functions, but your description of 3,4 doesn't really capture that.  I don't know whether it is important in your application to distinguish them, since you haven't said what your application is.

Comment: Do you suggest to ask my question better, i.e. to improve it? How would I do?

Comment: I would suggest that you explain why you are considering these functions and what you hope to do with them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71265/discussion-between-hans-stricker-and-nate-eldredge).

Comment: What does finitely many "switches" between $0$ and $1$ mean? Do you mean $f$ is continuous everywhere except for a finite subset of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Yes, obviously I just mean "continuous everywhere except for a fiinite subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and compactly supported". My question is for a compact - and maybe standard - way to specify such a function.

Comment: I've also read the term "non-Zeno signals" (e.g. [here](https://ac.els-cdn.com/S0304397502003316/1-s2.0-S0304397502003316-main.pdf?_tid=97ec9e36-f450-11e7-b418-00000aab0f01&acdnat=1515401444_ec312a345720bc5e1cd75d8c1777e10d)).

Comment: A $\{0,1\}$-valued function is also called characteristic function (of a subset). These subsets are boolean combinations of intervals, with the additional restriction of being bounded.